# How to manage a test database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am currently working on an application that uses a SQL Server 2008 database that sits internally on a LAN.  I am having two problems related to managing the database:

1. Currently, I have 2 databases in SQL server, one for test and one for production, and I copy tables and views etc... between these two databases when deploying changes.  I'm assuming there is a better way to manage pushing changes from the test database to the production database, can anyone point me in the right direction here?
2. I do a good portion of my work remotely, so I have installed SQL Server 2008 Express to my laptop and run a 3rd copy of the database locally.  Is this the best option for doing remote work?  The solution I've been looking for in this situation is to expose my test database to the web with a limited user that I could use for when I am developing remotely.  Is this feasible/recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that using my own, local copy of SQL Server Developer Edition on my notebook is the best way to do dev work overall; then a separate test and production database on servers. I like keeping my local dev server so that I am never at the mercy of connections to do dev work.

As a principle, I don't expose SQL servers publicly ever, so working through a VPN is the only way I can access my typical test/production servers. If my dev server was there, too; I would often be unable to do dev work when, for example, I am at a location where VPN pass-through is not permitted.

As for updating the production/test databases; I always generate change scripts when ever I change the dev server, and then keep them organized so they can be applied to the test and then later production servers. You can generate those scripts via SQL Server Management Studio or Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the cleanest most repeable way is to use a real build process for your database code and objects.  First put all your database code and objects in source control. Then use DBGHOST to create upgrade scripts to get your production database upgraded.  As part of this you can create output that will create a empty dev database that matches any given release easily when using DBGhost. We have been using for about 3 years now and wouldn't do it any otherway.  Check out there site for a full walk through. Well well worth the money. Did I say it's well worth the money?

http://www.innovartis.co.uk/

Comment: Thanks for the link!  It looks very interesting, planning on starting the evaluation shortly.